# Is a spacer needed for the drive-side when installing a bottom bracket kickstand on the NDS?

Tags: bottom-bracket, kickstand

I saw this kickstand on eBay:

[image]

It mounts on the bottom bracket. When installing this, should a spacer also be installed on the other side of the bottom bracket?

Right now, my crankset is a Shimano 105 FC-5700 with the inner chainring removed and my cassette is a 10-speed 105 11-28T. I was just wondering if a spacer would be added to the drive side, would that affect the chainline much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are intended to clamp around the cup itself.

Spindles have essentially zero spline engagement to lose. You can't really put spacers under road outboard BB cups.

Comment: Oh, you mean they go wrap around the cup of the bb (like a shim for tubes) and not behind/under it?

Comment: Yep, they clamp around the cup.